# RESideMenu: Side menu for iOS 7 to support both left and right menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am using [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) to implement an iOS 7 style side menu with parallax effect, but I come across a situation where I need to implement the side menu for both right and left sides just like the old Facebook iOS application where the right menu was for friends list and the left menu for the navigation.

Comment: RESideMenu now implements this as standard.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to do for right item menu and it works by editing the value in RESideMenu.m at line :

```
if (!_contentViewInLandscapeOffsetCenterX)                                 
        _contentViewInLandscapeOffsetCenterX = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) + 30.f;

if (!_contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX)
    _contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX  = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) + 30.f;
```

changing the +30.f to -300.f or more to slide the view (space and view's width) to left.
To your situation you may need to duplicate the function to make one for right one for left.
I hope this help you or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple to extend RESideMenu to include a third controller. You can adjust the `contentViewInLandscapeOffsetCenterX` and `contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX` to show on left or right side respectively.

If you don't feel like doing this, find an alternative solution at a site like [www.cocoacontrols.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but you know I want to extend RESideMenu and not looking for another alternative, so can you please explain more how can I add a third controller so I can for example do something like this: 

`[[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navCont menuViewController:menucont rightViewController:right];` 

or anything like that so then I can open another menu from the right as well as the left

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome and simple library

https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu

which supports left and right menus and fully customizable

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other libraries that uses same slide menu animation like RESideMenu. I found one, please see this link:

https://github.com/heroims/LeftRightSlider

Answer (score 0):

In RESideMenu.m

adjust the values like below

**_contentViewInLandscapeOffsetCenterX = 100.f;**

**_contentViewInPortraitOffsetCenterX  = 100.f;**

have fun.